# Given an expected average return and a set of possible outcomes, find reasonable probabilities for each outcome

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions

I'll start this by apologizing for my ignorance in mathematics. I'm trying to solve a problem for my job as a game designer. Basically I have a gacha machine that can give different random outcomes, and I have to choose the probability for each of those outcomes.

To simplify the problem, lets assume the possible outcomes are

1000/2000/5000/10000 Coins

10/20 Spins

2000/5000 Experience

1 Shield

Given these outcomes, which I arbitrarily picked, I'd like to define a probability for each one of them so that the average return per spin will match:

Coins - 3000, Spins - 0.1, Experience - 2500, Shields - 0.1

Because if I can get to define an average like this, balancing the game becomes much easier, as I can assume a relatively linear progression, decide costs based on that, and then scale everything up with some multipliers to make players feel like they are making progress. Sadly, I'm not sure how to solve this, and even using ChatGPT, I couldn't find a resonable solution, the AI gets stuck in a loop.

Comment: This to me looks like there could be infinite amount of probabilities. Of course on certain things. Do you mean by linear progression that for example that it is 2 times more likely you get 1000 coins than getting 2000 coins, and how does it it compare to getting 5000 coins, cause if it is 5 times more likely, than that wouldn't be linear progression.

Comment: "even using ChatGPT," , never use this useless tool.

Answer (score 2):

Expressing the expectations as a function of the separate probabilities is simple. Let's start by notating the probabilities:

| Event | Probability |
| --- | --- |
| 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000 coins | $p_{1c}, p_{2c}, p_{5c}, p_{10c}$ |
| 10, 20 spins | $p_{1s}, p_{2s}$ |
| 2000, 5000 experience | $p_{2x}, p_{5x}$ |
| 1 shield | $p_d$ |

Then we have $p_{1c} + p_{2c} + p_{5c} + p_{10c} + p_{1s} + p_{2s} + p_{2x} + p_{5x} + p_{d} = 1$, and also:

- Expected coins $ = 1000 p_{1c} + 2000 p_{2c} + 5000 p_{5c} + 10000 p_{10c} = 3000$, so $p_{1c} + 2 p_{2c} + 5 p_{5c} + 10 p_{10c} = 3$
- Expected spins $ = 10 p_{1s} + 20 p_{2s} = 0.1$, so $p_{1s} + 2 p_{2s} = 0.01$
- Expected experience $ = 2000 p_{2x} + 5000 p_{5x} = 2500$, so $2 p_{2x} + 5 p_{5x} = 2.5$
- Expected shields $ = p_d = 0.1$

At this point, we have 5 equations and 9 unknowns, meaning there are 4 degrees of freedom - although the probability of receiving a shield is already fixed, so you could reduce this to having 4 equations in 8 unknowns instead. In other words, there are an infinite number of possible solutions, but (with some restrictions) you can introduce 4 more constraints or arbitrary choices to force a single result.

What those constraints are is up to you - you might want to fix the relative probability of getting coins vs spins vs experience, which would essentially be adding constraints of the form $p_{1c} + p_{2c} + p_{5c} + p_{10c} = \alpha(p_{1s} + p_{2s}) = \beta(p_{2x} + p_{5x})$, which will fix everything except the coin probabilities that you can then tweak.

Speaking from the perspective of *game design* rather than mathematics, my advice would be to just make a spreadsheet and experiment with various options. Maybe even make a little prototype and see how it feels to spin the wheel with various options, because a mathematically perfect formula is no match for actual player experience.